# File.Exists isn't find the document but it is there

Tags: c#, console-application

So something must be wrong with my string.

I am grabbing the value from a SQL database which comes out like this:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    // Row Values
    // 0 = UID
    // 1 = CreatedDate
    // 2 = Location
    documentID = reader.GetGuid(0);
    fileName = reader.GetSqlValue(0).ToString() + ".zip";
    location = reader.GetString(2);
    createdDate = reader.GetDateTime(1);
```

The values returned from the database are as follows:

```
GUID: DC5A30D7-D528-4BA4-AA5A-5ECEB2CD9006
fileName: DC5A30D7-D528-4BA4-AA5A-5ECEB2CD9006.zip
Location: \\192.168.22.1\documentation


if (!DoesFileExist(location + fileName))
{
    // Log error to database
}

static bool DoesFileExist(string location)
        {
            bool doesExist = false;
            if (File.Exists(location))
            {
                doesExist = true;
            }

            return doesExist;
        }
```

When it gets to the part File.Exists(location) it passes over it as if it dind't exist.  Bur it does...  When I navigate to it in an Explorer I find the zip file just fine...

What am I doing wrong here?

```
UID CreatedDate Location
DC5A30D7-D528-4BA4-AA5A-5ECEB2CD9006    2009-10-28 11:17:06.690 \\192.168.22.1\documentation
```

Comment: instead of `location + fileName` try `Path.Combine(location,filename)`

Comment: Incidentally, you could just write `return File.Exists(location)` (or just use `File.Exists` to begin with..)

Comment: @tnw your edit is wrong. There are two backslashes in the original question. I rolled it back. now edit it again.

Comment: @Daniel yeah that is how it was originally made, then I added a method to do some extra work and wound up not using it.

Comment: @I4V No, there are not. Your edit added one which is why I removed it.

Comment: @tnw Yes there are. just try to edit the question You'll see them. It is in original form now (I rolled the qestion back to its original form)

Comment: @I4V Apologies, that's really strange... for me when it's displayed, shows a single slash, and when edited shows two. Whats with that?

Comment: @tnw what you see is not necessarily what is *really* in question. (SO processes the text to *beautify*)

Comment: @I4V I don't know what that means. I'll post this up on meta, that's very strange behavior.

Comment: @tnw To make the story short, don't edit the question which may change the its meaning (like removing one `\\` after my edit which was just about formatting)

Comment: @I4V I'm very well aware of that. Obviously I had thought you had changed its meaning.

Comment: And @JamesWilson . Please be carefull when posting a question. You have enough reps to know how SO's text formatting works.

Answer (score 3):

As it is written in the example above, the `Location + Filename` doesn't produce a correct full filename. There is no backslash to separate the path from the filename.
I suggest to use the appropriate method `Path.Combine` from the class ([System.IO.Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx)) to make the correct full filename

```
if (!DoesFileExist(Path.Combine(location, fileName)))
```

Comment: this answer helped solve my problem that was really hard..  escaping the backslash helped. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The way I see it, you're sending: "\192.168.22.1\documentationDC5A30D7-D528-4BA4-AA5A-5ECEB2CD9006.zip" to the method.

Try putting another "\" there.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time I have a problem like that, it is because of permissions. Often, the user for the file explorer is different that is trying to find the file with file exists. If everything is correct with the location, the next place to look would be the permissions.